# PHP CURL How can I configure this to not show the response?

Tags: php, curl

This is a simple piece of code provided from Pushover, they offer an API to use basic webhooks or simple code as a way of triggering push notifications. I'm trying to hide the CURL response, this code returns an ID for the request. I added the return transfer and verbose sections after reading up on this a bit but I've had no success. What do I need to remove / add to make these request ID's stop appearing?

```
curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    "token" => "API_KEY",
    "user" => "USER_KEY",
    "message" => $pushlogin,
  ),
  CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD => true,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 0,
));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: try $a = curl_exec($ch);

Comment: Didn't change the outcome at all, any other ideas?

Comment: By right the return transfer flag should force responses to return from curl_exec. Perhaps the ID was echoed out from other lines?

Comment: This line: CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, should be taking care of it.

Comment: As @LionelChan said, is there another spot where you might be echo'ing?

Comment: I went and register an account with pushover. Your code works fine actually and nothing was emitted from the lines above. I guess something else is echoing

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the location of the return transfer setting, it needed to be outside of the curl array.

This code below works, hopefully this helps another PUSHOVER user.

```
curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    "token" => "API_KEY",
    "user" => "USER_KEY",
    "message" => 'Test Message',
  ),
  CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD => true,
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```